# Create a timer triggering next iteration of a loop

Tags: c, goto

I have to realize a C program aimed at testing various sorting algorithms. I need to test each algorithm on 15 different array sizes, and do 20 tests for each size. The program then calculate the average time for the 20 tests.

My problem is: I would want a 20-tests serie to stop if it goes for longer than five minutes, but I do not want to crash the program: I want to test the algorithm for the next array size.

So, I put in place a five minute alarm in my main function:

```
signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);

//Test loop
NEXTTEST: while(maxValues[count + 1] <= MAX){
    ++count;
    int max = maxValues[count];

    alarm(60);
..............
```

And here is my alarmHandler:

```
void alarmHandler(int sig){
    printf("Signal %d détecté, arrêt de la série de test en cours...\n", sig);
    goto NEXTTEST;
}
```

As you can see, I would like to say, in my handler: "If you are triggered (if the alarm goes off), then go back to the NEXTTEST label, increment the size of the array, and go on with the tests on this size"

Except that is of course impossible, knowing that the declaration of my NEXTTEST label is in my main, while my alarmHandler is a separate function.

How could I go around this problem to create my timer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not change `alarm` and use `sleep` instead?

Comment: If there is  a danger that tested algorithms enter an infinite loop, you can use either long jumps (see `setjmp` and `longjmp`) or run the algos in a separate thread.

Comment: How would you do that? Isn't `sleep` blocking the program? (sorry, I am not well versed in C at all)

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps using multiple threads. But goto is definitely the wrong solution

Comment: The solution with setjmp and longjmp worked for me. I know it's certainly not optimal and kinda dirty, but I am too inexperienced to go in threads and the like. Thanks to everyone.